# How stable is MySQL 5.4

Tags: mysql

I have just found out about [MySql 5.4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-5.4-features/en/index.html) –

- How stable is this version?
- Where can I find more information on this version?

Comment: I think this belongs on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 5.4 is a preview/test release, first one under Oracle. As a test release is not intend to be used on a production stations.

They say that the most important change in 5.4 was to introduce [MySQL Optimizer](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/How_does_the_MySQL_Optimizer_work) which makes some of the queries run 90% faster.

Oracle wants to release MySQL more often and be more open for community ideas and use more community code.

Comment: Oracle did not have anything to do this with the 5.4 release.

Comment: I meant the fact that it was released after Oracle bought Sun Microsystems which bought MySQL AB earlier.

Answer (score 1):

5.4 is officially a preview release, so not officially recommended for production yet.  However, I do know of quite a few larger websites that are using it in production thanks to the terrific gains in performance.

As far as more information:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-5.4-features/en/index.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/news-5-4-0.html

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-54.html